# Fixed Heading tables with CSS Styling issue in IE

Tags: html, css

After intense levels of investigation into fixed table headers I stumbled across a fairly nice way to do this. However, I have to make it fully cross browser compatible.

I've searched high and low for another way to do what this does and I am coming up stummped.

The code below works in FF as far as I can test (the misaligned links are not a massive issue but at same time are annoying)

**However, in IE there is white space between the headings that I cannot appear to get rid of whilst maintaining the styles.** This is supposed to go back to IE6, but most of us are on IE8 and up and have same issue everywhere.

The scrolling works fine so the pasted table is just a sample of what I have to use as the data is long. The 16px margin-right is to compensate for the scroll bar as it appears.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Styling (apologies for compacting it)

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
table {
    width:100%;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    vertical-align:center;
}
th {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
}
.container {
    position:relative;
    padding:1.6em 0 0 0;
    width:80%;
    background:#fff;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.scroll {
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:19.6em;
}
.container thead tr {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    margin-right:16px;
    background:#fff;
}
.container th, .container td {
    width:100em;
}
td {
    background:#e5f1f4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:100%;
}
th {
    background:#328aa4;
    color:#fff;
    border-top: 3px double #ccc;
    border-bottom: 3px double #ccc;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-align:center;
}
tr.alt td {
    background-color: #f8fbfc;
}
tfoot {
    display:none;
}
table a:visited, table a:active, table a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
}
table a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background-color: #B0E2FF;
    display: block;
}
div.headalign {
    text-align: left;
    font-style:italic;
}
</style>
```

Page Code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="scroll">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><p>Product Code</p></th>
            <th><p>Design Name</p></th>
            <th><p>Ricoh</p></th>
            <th><p>Nashuatec</p></th>
            <th><p>Rex Rotary</p></th>
            <th><p>Gestetner</p></th>
            <th><p>Infotec</p></th>
            <th><p>Lanier</p></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th><p>Product Code</p></th>
            <th><p>Design Name</p></th>
            <th><p>Ricoh</p></th>
            <th><p>Nashuatec</p></th>
            <th><p>Rex Rotary</p></th>
            <th><p>Gestetner</p></th>
            <th><p>Infotec</p></th>
            <th><p>Lanier</p></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8"><div class="headalign"><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm"> 1022/1027/1032, 2022/2027/2032 series</a></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">B022</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">Russian C2a</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm"> 1022</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">2205</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">2238</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">2212</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">IS 2022</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">5622</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">B027</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">Russian C2b</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm"> 1027</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">2705</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">2738</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">2712</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">IS 2027</a></td>
        <td><a href="../contents/af1022_1027.htm">5627</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "white space". Are you referring to the leading between the text or to actual gaps in color? Is it your intention to hide that fist row of the table (.headalign) behind the header rows?

Comment: Sorry I could have explained better. Basically between each <th> there is a white line that looks like its padding the column headers. So yeah it would be gaps in the colour as im trying to aim for solid column headers. The head align is there just to left align the colspan rows as opposed to center them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this -----> [JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ebuqav/2/edit)

All I did was remove the absolute positioning from the header rows, and remove the 1.6em top padding you had on the #container div. You were basically adding 1.6ems of space at the top, then moving the table up to cover that space. Unless there's some unexplained reason for that, there was no point to it.

Updated JSBin -------> [HERE](http://jsbin.com/axuluk/6/edit)

```
.container thead tr {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100%; /* <---- this line added and right: 300; was removed ---- */
margin-right:16px;
background:#fff;
}
```

and

```
th {
background:#328aa4;
color:#fff;
    padding: 2px 0; /* <---- This Line added to compensate for white space below header row.----- */
border-top: 3px double #ccc;
border-bottom: 3px double #ccc;
/*  padding: 1px 5px;*/
font-variant: small-caps;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
/*  padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;*/
text-align:center;  
}
```

Comment: Problem is I have been asked to include fixed table headings without having to edit too many pages (about 30 all together) each with different columns and data, some of them are fairly large tables. The absolute is what fixed it and the 1.6em was what compensated the data being covered by the fixed heading so still viewalbe.

Comment: Data is still covered in your code unless the window is wide. Smaller screen sizes cover that top .headalign div, which is why I asked about it in the beginning. Unfortunately, it's a needle vs. haystack issue if there's more code which needs to be worked around.

Comment: a paste of the full code is here...http://jsbin.com/axuluk/2/edit, it behaves oddly though on there, where the fixed header resizes until you refresh or reload. on there the code doesnt get covered by the heading when it renders right. Think it might be a case of back to drawing board

Comment: I updated my answer above. Managed to keep the position and container padding.. but compensate.